# "No components in the package to retrieve." when retrieving source from package.xml

Tags: package, retrieve

when I attempted to retrieve the source from org. I got this error on output: "No components in the package to retrieve."
Here is my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.3.0</version>
</Package>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dumb mistake was when I stored my package.xml file in the force-app folder instead of the manifest. When I created a manifest folder and move the package.xml file inside it, I could retrieve the source successfully. Hope it can help everyone.